# Meaning of this line in Candida by Shaw

Tags: meaning, george-bernard-shaw, orthography, candida

There is a speech by Lexy in the beginning of Act I when he is talking to Proserpine:

> LEXY. Ah, if you women only had the same clue to Man's strength that you have to his weakness, Miss Prossy, there would be no Woman Question.

What do "Man's strength" and "Woman Question" mean? What does the whole line mean altogether? Are man and woman personified here because they begin with capital letters in the speech? Also, "Question" begins with a capital letter. What is the significance of this?

Text: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/4023/4023-h/4023-h.htm

Comment: It seems as though ["the Woman Question"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_woman_question) was a well-known concept in [19th-century literature](https://www.wwnorton.com/college/english/nael/victorian/topic_2/welcome.htm).